# Android калькулятор, как организовать вывод целых чисел

Tags: java, android

Написал калькулятор, первое приложение.Не могу понять, почему когда получается результат целое число, оно не переходит в int а выводиться как дробное например выводится "3.0" вместо "3"(последние 5 строк кода)

```
package com.example.leon.calculat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText etNum;
    Button btnOne,btnTwo,btnThree,btnFour ,btnFive,btnSix,btnSeven, btnEight, btnNine, btnZero;
    Button btnAdd, btnDiv, btnMul, btnSub, btnAnswer,btnClin,btn_back,btn_l_bracket,btn_r_bracket;
    Button btn_dot;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // находим элементы
        etNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNum);
        btnOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
        btnTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);
        btnThree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnThree);
        btnFour = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFour);
        btnFive = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFive);
        btnSix = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSix);
        btnSeven = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSeven);
        btnEight = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEight);
        btnNine = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNine);
        btnZero = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnZero);
        btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnDiv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);
        btnMul = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMul);
        btnSub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
        btnAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer);
        btnClin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClin);
        btn_back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        btn_l_bracket = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_l_bracket);
        btn_r_bracket = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_r_bracket);
        btn_dot = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_dot);
        //прописываем обработчик
        btnOne.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnThree.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnFour.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnFive.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSix.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSeven.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnEight.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnNine.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnZero.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnDiv.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnMul.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSub.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAnswer.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnClin.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_back.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_l_bracket.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_r_bracket.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_dot.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        Editable str =  etNum.getText();
        switch (v.getId()){
            // определяем нажатую кнопку и выполняем соответствующую операцию
            case R.id.btnOne: str= str.append(btnOne.getText());
                etNum.setText(str);break;
            case R.id.btnTwo: str =str.append(btnTwo.getText());
                etNum.setText(str); break;
            case R.id.btnThree: str = str.append(btnThree.getText());
                etNum.setText(str); break;
            case R.id.btnFour: str.append(btnFour.getText());
                etNum.setText(str);break;
            case R.id.btnFive: str = str.append(btnFive.getText());
                etNum.setText(str);break;
            case R.id.btnSix: str = str.append(btnSix.getText());
                etNum.setText(str);break;
            case R.id.btnSeven: str = str.append(btnSeven.getText());
                etNum.setText(str);break;
            case R.id.btnEight:str = str.append(btnEight.getText());
                etNum.setText(str);break;
            case R.id.btnNine: str = str.append(btnNine.getText());
                etNum.setText(str);break;
            case R.id.btnZero: str = str.append(btnZero.getText());
                etNum.setText(str);break;
            case R.id.btn_l_bracket: str.append(btn_l_bracket.getText());
                etNum.setText(str);break;
            case R.id.btn_r_bracket: str.append(btn_r_bracket.getText());
                etNum.setText(str);break;
            case R.id.btn_dot: str.append(btn_dot.getText());
                etNum.setText(str);break;
            case R.id. btn_back:
               StringBuilder bac = new StringBuilder(str);
                int lastback=str.length();
               if (bac.length()>1)
               bac.setLength(lastback-1);
                etNum.setText(bac);break;
            case R.id.btnAdd:str=str.append(btnAdd.getText());
                int lastAdd=str.length()-2;
                char chLastAdd= str.charAt(lastAdd);
                //игнорирует один оператор '-' в начале пустой оператор
                if(str.charAt(1)=='-'&&str.length()==2){
                    etNum.setText(" -");}
                //меняет  на оператор '+', если до этого был введен другой оператор
                 else if ((chLastAdd=='-')||(chLastAdd=='/')||(chLastAdd=='*')||(chLastAdd=='+')){
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
                    sb.setCharAt(lastAdd,'+');
                    sb.setLength(lastAdd + 1);
                    etNum.setText(sb);
                    //не дает ввести вначале пустой строки оператор'+'
                 }else if(str.charAt(1)=='+'){
                     etNum.setText(" ");}
                  else
                    etNum.setText(str);
                break;

            case R.id.btnDiv: str=str.append(btnDiv.getText());
                int lastDiv =str.length()-2;
                char chLastDiv =str.charAt(lastDiv);
                //игнорирует один оператор '-' в начале пустой строки
                if(str.charAt(1)=='-'&&str.length()==2){
                    etNum.setText(" -");}
                //меняет  на оператор '/', если до этого был введен другой оператор
                else if((chLastDiv=='/')||(chLastDiv=='*')||(chLastDiv=='-')||(chLastDiv=='+')){
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
                    sb.setCharAt(lastDiv,'/');
                    sb.setLength(lastDiv + 1);
                    etNum.setText(sb);
                    //не дает ввести вначале пустой строки оператор'/'
                }else if(str.charAt(1)=='/'){
                    etNum.setText(" ");
                }else
                    etNum.setText(str);
                break;

            case R.id.btnSub: str.append(btnSub.getText());
                int lastSub = str.length()-2;
                char chLastSub = str.charAt(lastSub);
                //меняет  на оператор '-', если до этого был введен другой оператор
                if((chLastSub=='-')||(chLastSub=='+')||(chLastSub=='/')||(chLastSub=='*')){
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
                    sb.setCharAt(lastSub,'-');
                    sb.setLength(lastSub + 1);
                    etNum.setText(sb);
                }else
                    etNum.setText(str);
                break;

            case R.id.btnMul: str.append(btnMul.getText());
                int lastMul = str.length()-2;
                char chLastMul = str.charAt(lastMul);
                //игнорирует один оператор '-' в начале пустой строки
                if(str.charAt(1)=='-'&&str.length()==2){
                etNum.setText(" -");}
                //меняет  на оператор '*', если до этого был введен другой оператор
                else if((chLastMul=='/')||(chLastMul=='*')||(chLastMul=='-')||(chLastMul=='+')){
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
                    sb.setCharAt(lastMul, '*');
                    sb.setLength(lastMul+1);
                    etNum.setText(sb);
                    //не дает ввести вначале пустой строки оператор'*'
                }else if(str.charAt(1)=='*'){
                    etNum.setText(" ");}

                else
                    etNum.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.btnAnswer:
                //выводит результат введенного числового выражения
                PolishNatation answ = new PolishNatation();
                String exp = etNum.getText().toString();
                answ.value(exp);
                String expOut = String.valueOf(answ.value(exp));
                etNum.setText(" "+expOut);
                break;
            case R.id.btnClin:
                etNum.setText(" ");

            default:
                System.out.print("bag");
        }
    }

    class PolishNatation{
        // присваивание операторам приоритетов
        boolean isOperator(char c){
            return c=='+'||c=='-'||c=='/'||c=='*';
        }
        int prority(char oper){
            if(oper=='*'||oper=='/'){
                return 1;
            }else if(oper=='+'||oper=='-'){
                return 0;
            }else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        // выполнение действий
        void calculatoin(LinkedList<Float>st,char oper) {
            float firstValue = st.removeLast();
            float secondValue = st.removeLast();
            switch (oper) {
                case '+':
                    st.add(secondValue + firstValue);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    st.add(secondValue - firstValue);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    st.add(secondValue / firstValue);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    st.add(secondValue * firstValue);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.print("bag");
            }
        }
        float value(String exp) {
            //убирает пробелы с введенного выражения;меняеет "(-" на "(0-"
            exp = exp.replace(" ","").replace("(-","(0-");
            if (exp.charAt(0)=='-'){
                //если первым введен '-' то меняем "-" на "0-"
                exp = "0"+exp;
            }

            LinkedList<Float> someValue = new LinkedList<>();// для чисел
            LinkedList<Character> someOperator = new LinkedList<>();//для операторов
            for (int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++) {
                char compare = exp.charAt(i);
                if (compare == '(') {
                    someOperator.add('(');
                } else if (compare == ')') {
                    while (someOperator.getLast() != '(') {
                        calculatoin(someValue, someOperator.removeLast());
                    }
                    someOperator.removeLast();
                } else if (isOperator(compare)) {
                    while (!someOperator.isEmpty() && prority(someOperator.getLast()) >= prority(compare)) {
                        calculatoin(someValue, someOperator.removeLast());
                    }
                    someOperator.add(compare);
                }
                else {
                    //если operand число (целое или дробное) передаем его в  someValue
                    String operand = "";
                    while (i < exp.length() && (Character.isDigit(exp.charAt(i))||exp.charAt(i)=='.')) {
                        operand = operand + exp.charAt(i++);
                    }
                    i--;
                    someValue.add(Float.parseFloat(operand));
                }
            }
            while (!someOperator.isEmpty()) {
                calculatoin(someValue, someOperator.removeLast());
            }
            float a = someValue.getFirst();
            int b = (int)a;
             if(a %1==0){
                return b;}else
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

**Обновление**

Получается, что у меня убого, но всё равно выводит число в виде "3,0" а не "3". В коде последние 5 строк (`float a = someValue.getFirst();` // результат вычислений, если это целое число, то `if(a %1==0){ return b;` затем значение  "b" передается в строку вывода - код при нажатии кнопки  `case R.id.btnAnswer:`)

Каким образом лучше переписать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это норма, т.к. у вас тип данных float, а он поддерживает числа после запятой, вы лучше покажите код, где вы выводите данные, скорее всего вы так задали вывод данных, что у вас показывает 0 после запятой. Если вас так пугает этот 0, то вы можете делать проверку на то, что чисел после запятой нету и перед выводом делать либо приведение к int, хотя это убого, либо грамотно оперировать с String.format(); Вот пример работы с [String.format](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/)

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @СергейЛеоновец Вы уж простите, но мне с этого немного смешно, я сейчас вам объясню, вам тоже будет смешно)) Я прочитал ваши последние 5 строк. Вы делаете под конец преобразование к int, но это абсолютно лишнее действие, т.к. функция всё равно возвращает float, т.е. вы делаете преобразование к int, а когда выполняете return, то ваше значение всё равно преобразовывается к float, вы попробуйте сделать преобразование к int с результатом функции.

Comment: Спасибо! все понял)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте нужное число округлить методом Math.round(ваше_число);